# Fastest way to convert NVARCHAR value to XML

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq, t-sql

In a database that I inherited to support there are several tables with an `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column containing a blob of untyped XML data. I have been tasked with searching these XML blobs for references to a given ID, then stop when the first reference is found and report what was found. I am currently looping through each row, converting the blob to XML then using XQuery to search the blob for the ID.

However, the initial conversion of the NVARCHAR value to XML is taking way too long due to the large number of rows in the tables. Below is an example of the code I'm using to convert each blob, with `HistoryID` being the PK and the value changing to grab the next XML blob from `XMLData`:

```
SELECT @XML = CONVERT(XML, XMLData)
FROM dbo.History
WHERE HistoryID = 1;
```

I have also tried to leverage C# and LINQ, but the XML blobs are too large to pass back and forth from .NET to SQL Server. Unfortunately I also cannot modify the existing tables without breaking the application. Is there a better way to get these XML blobs into a searchable form or am I just SOL?

Comment: Do you need to convert it to xml? Can you not simply search the nvarchar with patindex instead?

Comment: can you show an example of the xml structure?..

Comment: How big is the typical XML blob per row?

Comment: @JamieD77, unfortunately the XML contains a significant amount of PII data, but I can say that they appear to be about 3,000-4,000 lines long and nest as deeply as 8 layers in spots.

Comment: @WillC Looks like a min of 22 bytes, max of 340 MB and an average of 6 MB.

Comment: @momar No I don't necessarily need to convert to XML for searching, but I thought that would be easier than trying to identify all of the possible patterns in the string. If another format would be easier I'm open to suggestions though.

Comment: Your syntax `SELECT @XML =` makes me think, that you are doing this in a loop... Some questions: Do you need this as a one-time-action or repeatedly? Would it be possible to create a new column (or a 1:1-side-table) to store the converted values persistently? I'll poste a set-based approach in some minutes...

Comment: In addition to my answer I'd advise you - if ever possible - not only to store the converted XML but also to store the ID (and maybe other values you might be searching for) in dedicated indexed columns. If you are not allowed to modify the database you might even think of a separate database... Doing so will make your searches lightning fast...

Comment: @Shnugo Yes it is still open. I'm trying different things and so far nothing is faster than what I already have in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a loop... Try it like this

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl (ID INT,SomeColumn VARCHAR(100),YourXMLasString NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO #tbl VALUES
 (1,'Test 11','<root><id>100</id><more>abc</more></root>')
,(2,'Test 12','<root><id>100</id><more>abc</more></root>')
,(3,'Test 21','<root><id>200</id><more>def</more></root>')
,(4,'Test 22','<root><id>200</id><more>def</more></root>')
,(5,'Test 23','<root><id>200</id><more>def</more></root>')
,(6,'Test  3','<root><id>300</id><more>ghi</more></root>');

--Just take the id 200
SELECT *
FROM #tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(YourXMLasString AS XML)) AS A(RealXml)
WHERE RealXml.exist('/root[id=200]') = 1

--Now stop at the first with 200
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM #tbl
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST(YourXMLasString AS XML)) AS A(RealXml)
WHERE RealXml.exist('/root[id=200]') = 1
ORDER BY ID
GO

DROP TABLE #tbl;
```

### Some hints

Whenever you search for an ID **you do the conversion over and over** ... It would be **much faster** of course, if you **store the converted XML**.

If you are searching for the same values more often, it might be a good idea to read these values from your XML and store it in dedicated indexed columns...

With this you could add a column to the existing table

```
ALTER TABLE #tbl ADD RealXml XML;
GO
UPDATE #tbl SET RealXml=CAST(YourXMLasString AS XML);
SELECT * FROM #tbl;
```

And with this you could create a side table

```
CREATE TABLE #SideTable(RefID INT,RealXML XML);
INSERT INTO #SideTable
SELECT ID,CAST(YourXMLasString AS XML)
FROM #tbl;

SELECT * FROM #SideTable;
```

If the data is changing, you might think about a trigger to do the conversion and update of the side column/table immediately.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has ways of acting on XML in the database such as value, exist, nodes, query, and modify. The value property of a XML element is then queryable. More info: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/

Something like:

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(XML, XMLData).value('(/Updated/UserId)[1]', 'int') AS UpdatedId 
FROM History
WHERE CONVERT(XML, XMLData).exist('(/Updated/UserId)[1]') > 0
```

Would have to try it to see what happens if some of the xmldata blobs are as large as 360mb...

For performance, an XML index (if modifying the schema was possible) can be added to the table   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497.aspx.

Comment: I am doing something like this already for the search part, but that depends upon it being stored as XML in SQL Server already. Currently the data is sitting in an NVARCHAR field and the problem is converting that value to XML so I can search it, not the search itself.

Comment: Ok. The "cannot modify the existing tables"  being the important part.

Comment: Have you tried using .value on the coverted XmlData column?

Comment: "Cannot find either column "XMLData" or the user-defined function or aggregate "XMLData.value", or the name is ambiguous." Looks like the ".value" doesn't work on NVARCHAR data.

Comment: Was it something like? SELECT CONVERT(XML, XMLData).value('(/Updated/UserId)[1]', 'int')
    AS UpdatedId FROM History

Comment: The CONVERT part is the problem. It works, but takes several hours to convert all of the values from NVARCHAR to XML. That's why I'm looking for a better way search these values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113068/discussion-between-willc-and-steven-ball).

Answer (score 0):

```
    // xmlElement is the column read from DB , consider having an index on the field as well as batching the reads if its too big   
    public static List<History> DeserializeHistory(XElement xmlElement)
    {

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(List<History>));

        using (System.Xml.XmlReader reader = xmlElement.CreateReader())
        {

            return (List<History>)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }

    }
```